# Sending a String via Cable? Lightning Male to Male Cable?

Tags: ios, string, security, data-transfer, multipeer-connectivity

I need to send a string from one iPad to another Apple device securely. I'm currently using multi-peer connectivity to send a string via bluetooth, but I need it to be more secure.

Is there such thing as a lightning to lightning cable?
Or another way can I send a confidential string from a device to another, requiring maximum security?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if Apple supports this but you can try the TOB Cable:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/janulus/tob-cable-one-cable-for-everything

Answer (score 0):

MPC supports session encryption - have you considered that?  The security identity is (IMHO) kinda like SSL Pinning.

```
initWithPeer:securityIdentity:encryptionPreference:

typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger ,
   MCEncryptionPreference ) {
   MCEncryptionOptional                 = 0,
   MCEncryptionRequired                 = 1,
   MCEncryptionNone                     = 2,
};
```

Comment: Is that all thats required? I have implemented this as follows:
`-(void)setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName{

 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"peerID"] == nil)
{_peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] .. ];
}
else
{
_peerID  =  [NSKeyedUnnarchiver ..... ];
}
_session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
securityIdentity:nil
encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionRequired];
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger ,
MCEncryptionPreference ) {
MCEncryptionOptional = 0,
MCEncryptionRequired = 1,
MCEncryptionNone = 2,
};
_session.delegate = self;
}`

Comment: and also, how can I check its being encrypted?

Comment: Hard to read the example you provided, but if you don't provide a security identity, you could be communicating (with encryption) with a peer you might not know.  As for your other question, haven't had the need to verify but a packet sniffer would do it (but I'm sure there's a simpler way)